# JSON populate multiple select fields

Tags: jquery, json

I have a set of select fields `#jobstatus`, `#jobsize` etc...

These are used in several pages throughout a project.

In order to keep these select fields up to date across the project I'm trying to use getJSON to parse out the JSON values saved in external JSON files.

I want the option values for each select field to populate with the correct values from the corresponding JSON file.

The JSON arrays follow this format :

```
/*Job Status */    
[
    { "name": "All Job Statuses" },
    { "name": "To start" },
    { "name": "In progress" },
    { "name": "On hold" },
    { "name": "Completed" },
    { "name": "Cancelled"}
]

/*Job type */    
[
    { "name": "All Job Types" },
    { "name": "Development" },
    { "name": "Feature/Service" },
    { "name": "Task Submission" },
    { "name": "Bug/Fix" },
    { "name": "Chore" },
    { "name": "Misc/Other" },
    { "name": "Discussion/Planning" },
]
```

The corresponding html for the select fields is as follows:

```
<select id="jobstatus" class="json" ></select>
<select id="jobtypes" class="json" ></select>
```

I want to use a getJSON function to parse out the correct data for each select field, but I can't figure out how to get the script to run the getJSON function for each select field.

Here's my script so far:

```
$('#filter select.json' ).each(function () {
    var select = $(this, 'select');
    var selectid = select.prop('id');

    $(select).attr({
        required:'required',
        name: selectid
    }).addClass('form-control');  

    $.getJSON('js/' + selectid + 'data.json', function(data){
        var html = '';
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
            html += '<option';
            if(i == 0) { 
                html += ' selected';
            }; 
            if(i > 0) { 
                html += ' value="' + i + '"';
            }; 
            html += '>' + data[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        $('#' + selectid).append(html);
    });

    console.log('select ', select + ' , selectid ', selectid);
});
```

Where have I gone wrong? Only the first select filed `#jobstatus` is populating with the data from the first array, that is not what I was expecting.

Is there a benefit of merging these JSON files into one?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know you've done something wrong? What error are you getting?

Comment: Only the first select filed `#jobstatus` is populating with the first array, that is not what I was expecting.

Comment: no error. this code runs.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading I've solved the issue.

I've grouped my JSON arrays in to one file (jobsdata.php) and switched to `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON`, as I can add in an error fall back apposed to nothing hapenening.

The updated JSON to the following:

```
{
    "jobstatus": [
        { "name": "Select a Job Status"  },
        { "name": "To start" },
        { "name": "In progress" },
        { "name": "On hold" },
        { "name": "Completed" },
        { "name": "Cancelled" }
    ],
    "jobtype": [
        { "name": "Select a Job Type" },
        { "name": "Development" },
        { "name": "Feature/Service" },
        { "name": "Task Submission" },
        { "name": "Bug/Fix" },
        { "name": "Chore" },
        { "name": "Misc/Other" },
        { "name": "Discussion/Planning" }

    ]
}
```

My updated script:

```
$('#filter select.json' ).each(function () {
    var select = $(this, 'select');
    var selectid = $(this).prop('id');

    $(select).attr({
        required:'required',
        name: selectid
    }).addClass('form-control');  


    $.ajax({
        url: 'js/jobdata.json',
        dataType:'JSON',

        success:function(data){
            //clear the current content of the select
            $('#' + selectid).html('');
            //iterate over the data and append a select option
            $(select).each(function () {
                var html = '';
                var len = data[selectid].length;
                for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
                    html += '<option';
                    if(i == 0) { 
                        html += ' selected';
                    }; 
                    if(i > 0) { 
                        html += ' value="' + i + '"';
                    }; 
                    html += '>' + data[selectid][i].name + '</option>';
                }                
                $('#' + selectid).append(html);
            })
        },
        error:function(){
            //if there is an error append a 'selectid unavailable' option
            $('#' + selectid).html('<option id="-1">' + selectid + ' unavailable</option>');
        }
    });  

    console.log('selectid ', selectid);

});
```